# Reference frames in relativity

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames

> Here is how Sachs and Wu do it in *General Relativity for
> Mathematicians* (1977).
>
> They start by defining a *spacetime* to be a connected 4-dimensional,
> oriented, and time-oriented Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$ together with
> the Levi-Civita connection $D$ of $g$ on $M$.
>
> Then they define an *observer* in $M$ to be a future-pointing timelike
> curve $\gamma$ such that $|\gamma_*|=1$. (This latter condition is
> just for convenience.)
>
> Finally, they define a *reference frame* on a spacetime $M$ to be a
> vector field, each of whose integral curves is an observer.

If one defines the reference frame on spacetime $M$ to be a vector field, what does "moving frame of reference relative to another" mean from the perspective of vector fields?

Comment: What are you quoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two vector fields defining frames of reference, then $\delta V= V_2-V_1$ is a spacelike vector field that gives the relative velocity between these two frames.

Note that this relative velocity $\delta V$ is itself a vector field and can therefore vary from point to point. It can be zero at some points while taking non-zero values at others.

Answer (score 0):

If a reference frame is defined as a vector field as described above then two different reference frames will generally have different vectors at any given event. The angle between those two vectors is related to the relative velocity between the two corresponding observers.

Comment: How are you defining the angle between two timelike vectors?

Comment: @TimRias this is the rapidity https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/angles-in-minkowski-space.991133/#:~:text=However%2C%20the%20equivalent%20of%20angle,%2C%20like%20angles%2C%20they%20add.

Comment: The rapidity is not a regular angle but a hyperbolic angle.

Comment: @TimRias yes ..